# Order of initialization of attributes is confusing

Tags: python-attrs

I've been using attrs the following way:

```
@attr.mutable
class Foo:
    x: int = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int))


@attr.mutable
class Bar:
    x: int = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int))
    foo: Foo = attr.ib(
        default=attr.Factory(factory=lambda self: Foo(self.x), takes_self=True),
        validator=attr.validators.instance_of(Foo),
    )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Bar("5")
```

When I ran the code, I obviously got an error.

But, the not intuitive part for me was that the validator of the `Foo` class raised the error.

I may be wrong but according to this I assume that validator of the `x` attribute of the `Bar` comes after `Foo`'s.

Why is that? Would not it make more sense to validate `Bar`'s `x` attribute before passing it as an argument to `Foo`'s init method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When instantiating, defaults are [filled *before* the validators run](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#order-of-execution).

The `__init__` method doesn't know anything about the fact that `Foo` has a validator and `Foo` doesn't know, that `Bar` hasn't fully instantiated itself.

From the perspective of `Bar`, it calls the factory with the value of `x` that hasn't been validated yet (`"5"`).

From the perspective of `Foo`, it gets instantiated with a str and fails validation.